# Batch Insert data into database using web services in yii2 error

Tags: web-services, activerecord, yii, yii2, dao

I've tried for get data in web services at http://api.rajaongkir.com/dokumentasi/starter. And I was success show data in view browser. When I implementation for insert data with a lot of into database something any wrong. I don't know why.

This code for get data in web service at http://api.rajaongkir.com/dokumentasi/starter. And put in controllers/TestController.php

```
public function actionGetProvince($id=0)
    {
        $client = new client();
        $addUrl = ($id>0)?'id='.$id:'';
        $response = $client->createRequest()
                    ->setFormat(Client::FORMAT_JSON)
                    ->setMethod('get')
                    ->setUrl('http://api.rajaongkir.com/starter/province?'.$addUrl)
                    ->addHeaders(['key' => 'example'])
                    ->send();
        if ($response->isOk) {
            $content = \Yii\helpers\Json::decode($response->content);
            //$content['rajaongkir']['query']
            //$content['rajaongkir']['status']
            $results = $content['rajaongkir']['results'];
            if ($id > 0) {
                if (count($results)>0) {
                    echo $results['province_id'] . ' - ';
                    echo $results['province'] . '<br>';
                }
                else {
                    echo "blank";
                }
            } else {
                foreach ($results as $provinces) {
                    echo $provinces['province_id']." - ".$provinces['province']."<br>";
                }
            }
        } else {
            $content = \Yii\helpers\Json::decode($response->content);
            echo $content['rajaongkir']['status']['description'];
        }
    }
```

And this code for insert data with a lot of in database, and I put in file same.

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert('province', [
            'id_province' => $provinces['province_id'], 'name' => $provinces['province']
            ])->execute();
```

And the result error is :

> PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException : Missing argument 3 for yii\db\Command::batchInsert(), called in C:\wamp\www\basic_yii2\controllers\TestController.php on line 60 and defined

Comment: try with this. Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->batchInsert('province',['id_province','name'] ,[$provinces['province_id'], $provinces['province']])->execute();

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling `batchInsert()` properly.

See it in [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#batchInsert()-detail).

```
public $this batchInsert ( $table, $columns, $rows )
```

**$table** `string` The table that new rows will be inserted into.
**$columns** `array` The column names
**$rows** `array` The rows to be batch inserted into the table

Example:

```
$connection->createCommand()->batchInsert('user', ['name', 'age'], [
    ['Tom', 30],
    ['Jane', 20],
    ['Linda', 25],
])->execute();
```